# What is the difference between MSE in loss="mean_squared_error" and metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am training a neural network model using:

`model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()])`

What troubles me, is the difference between value of loss and metric in training history, while at first glance both should calculate the same thing.

```
Epoch 4/30
15484/15484 [==============================] - 135s 9ms/step - loss: 0.1212 - mean_squared_error: 0.1188 - val_loss: 0.1146 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.1120
Epoch 5/30
15484/15484 [==============================] - 135s 9ms/step - loss: 0.1198 - mean_squared_error: 0.1170 - val_loss: 0.1138 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.1109
Epoch 6/30
15484/15484 [==============================] - 131s 8ms/step - loss: 0.1187 - mean_squared_error: 0.1157 - val_loss: 0.1132 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.1101
```

Are they calculating MSE based on different things (batch vs whole epoch) or are implemented differently? I have searched through some documentation and did a little bit of googling but didn't find the answer.

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: What kind of dataset you are using and what are the number of classes in the dataset? The difference between the two is that the loss function `"mean_squared_error"` is used to train the model and to calculate the error during training, while the metric `tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()` is used to evaluate the performance of the model and calculate the error during testing. These two functions are equivalent, so there is no need to use both. You can simply use the `mean_squared_error` loss function.